# Is there a way to make an itemized labeled list not go through the margins?

Tags: enumerate, itemize

The following has the item name out of the margins:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item[very very very very very long item name] and here are its details
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I would like it not to go through the margins, but instead start at a place much more to the right.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Use a `description` environment. Why `itemize`?

Comment: A Bernard say, something like `\begin{description}
\item[\textbullet\ <-- if you liked, and very very very very very long item name] and here are its details\end{description}\end{document}`

Comment: thanks. embarrassingly enough, I forgot about the description environment.. that's what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option (apart from using `description`), is `enumitem` and its `multiline` option, allowing the label to wrap around. A specific labelwidth has to be set **after** `multiline`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[style=multiline,labelwidth=50pt]

\item[very very very very very long item name] and here are its details
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have long item heads only every now and then, it may be tedious to have to type `\item[\textbullet]` systematically. You can use the  `wide` option of `enumitem`, which makes left aligned labels instead of the default right-aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[wide, leftmargin=*]

\item[\itshape very very very very very long item name] and here are its details:
\lipsum[4]

\item \lipsum[11]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]